# Codeigniter : Multiple columns of the same row Update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, global

I am not able to update multiple columns of the same row with the row matching the userid in codeigniter.

My controller Code is :

exits.php

```html
 function update_act_on_resignation(){
    global $SITE,$USER;
   $data = array();
   $data['row'] = new stdClass();
   $data['row'] = $this->admin_init_elements->set_post_vals($this->input->post());
   $data['offices']=$this->mod_common->get_all_offices();
   $clients = currentuserclients();
   $data['roles'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('designation','status',"1' AND id > '0",'designation');
   get_city_state_country_array($data,array('cityid'=>$data['row']->cityid));
   $data['error_message'] = '';
   $data['row']->id = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $data['action'] = 'add';
   $data['heading'] = 'Add';
   $data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
   $data['path']=$path;
   $post_action = $this->input->post('action');
   if($post_action=='add' || $post_action =='update' ){
    $post_array = $this->input->post();
    $action = ($post_action == 'add')?'inserted':'updated';
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($SITE);die;
    echo $post_array['exit_type'] = 'Employee Initiated';
        echo $post_array[$id] = $USER->id; 
             echo $post_array['custom-105965']; 
             echo $post_array['manager_comments']; 
             echo $post_array['accept']; 
          echo $post_array['agreed_last_date']; 
   

     $data['success_message'] = $this->exit_common->update_get_resignation_to_act($post_array,$action);


     if($data['success_message'] == 'Record '.$action.' successfully'){
      $data['row'] = new stdClass();
      $data['row']->id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $data['row']->status = 1;

     }

   }
   
   $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/view_resignation_action', $data,true);
   echo "Resignation withdrawn successfully!";
   
   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
  }
```

I am echoing the results got from a form to check if i am receiving the sent form elements and i have received everything properly. i.e i am recieving 67 for $post_array[$id]  Yes for $post_array['custom-105965'] asd for $post_array['manager_comments'] Accept for $post_array['accept'] and 01-01-1970 as $post_array['agreed_last_date'] after the echo.

My Model code is:

exit_common.php

```html
 function update_get_resignation_to_act($post_array,$action){
   
   $this->load->database(); 
   $this->db->where('userids', $post_array['id']); 
   $dbdata['discussion'] =  $post_array['custom-105965']; 
   $dbdata['manager_comments'] =  $post_array['manager_comments']; 
     $dbdata['last_status'] =  $post_array['accept']; 
   $dbdata['agreed_date'] =  $post_array['agreed_last_date']; 
 
   $this->db->update('pr_resignation_requests', $dbdata);
    return;
      
   
   
  }
```

I think something is wrong with the model update function. But not able to figure out what is wrong as a similar function is working for updating a single column in db. Am i missing something? Its a mysql db.

My View Code is:

view_resignation_action.php

```html
<style>
label{font-weight:bold;}

.hbox .col {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
 width:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="new">
   <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
   Resignation Action
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb" >
            <li><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">People Connect</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>exits">Exit Tracker</a></li>
   <li class="active">Exit Details</li>
            
          </ol>
    </section>
 <input type="hidden" id="page_name" value="requests"> 
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <!-- Thought Day-->
                        <div class="panel wrapper clearfix m-b-none">
              <!-- Horizontal Form -->
              
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
     <?php if($error_message!=''){?>
        <div class="row-fluid return-message success-message <?php echo $msg_class; ?>"><?php echo $error_message;?></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
                <?php echo form_open('exits/update_act_on_resignation/',array('name'=>'addostcstevent','id'=>'addostcstevent','method'=>'post','autocomplete'=>'on','class'=>'form-horizontal'))?>
     <?php echo form_hidden(array('id'=>$USER->id,'action'=>$action));?>
     
     <?php foreach($rows as $row){ ?>
                  <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="control-group form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        
            <div class="controls">  
           <div class="col-md-5">
          
          <label class="control-label" style="text-align:left">Name of the employee </label>
          <div class="controls"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?>
          </div>
          
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
          
          </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
       <label class="control-label" style="text-align:left">Date of request </label><div class="controls">
          <?php echo $row->resignations_date; ?>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="clearfix"></div>     
     <div class="control-group form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
       <label class="control-label" style="text-align:left">Requested Last Working Date</label>
       <div class="controls">
       <div class="col-md-10">
         <?php echo $row->requested_date; ?>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
       <label class="control-label">Reason</label>
      <div class="controls">
       <div class="col-md-9">
       <?php echo $row->exit_type; ?>  
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
       <label class="control-label">Comments from Employee</label>
      <div class="controls">
       <div class="col-md-9">
       <?php echo $row->comments; ?>  
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     
     
     <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
     
     
     <fieldset id="f1" class="col-md-6 pull-left"> <!-- start fieldset -->
     

     <div class="label">
     


    </label>
</div>
<div class="input">

</div>
</div>
</td>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" style="text-align:left">
  
     <label class="control-label" style="text-align:left">Have you had a discussion with Employee?</label>
      <table>
       <td valign="top">
       <input id="custom-105965_0" class="custom-105965" name="custom-105965" value="Yes" type="radio">
       <label for="custom-105965_0">Yes
       <br>
       </label>
       </td>
       <td valign="top">
       <input id="custom-105965_1" class="custom-105965" name="custom-105965" value="No" type="radio">
       <label for="custom-105965_1">No
       
     </label>
    </td>
  </table>
            <td valign="top">
                <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-custom-105967-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
       <label class="control-label">Please enter your comments</label>
       <div class="controls">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       <textarea required class="form-control" name="manager_comments"></textarea>
        <!--<input placeholder="Please enter your comments" class="" id="dateofrequest" type="text" name="todays_date" value=""/> <br><br>-->
       </div>
       </div>
       
       <label class="control-label">Action</label>
       <div class="controls">
       <div class="col-md-9">
       <?php $dd_list = array(
        'Accept'   => 'Accepted',
        'Reject'   => 'Rejected',
        );
       echo form_dropdown('accept', $dd_list, 'Accept');  
       ?> 
       </div>
       </div>
       
       
       
       
      
       <label class="control-label">Agreed Last Working day</label>
       <div class="controls">
       <div class="col-md-9">
        <input placeholder="Agreed Last Working day" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="startdt" type="text" name="agreed_last_date" value="<?php if($row->requested_date!='') echo date("d-m-Y",$row->requested_date); ?>" required/>
       </div>
       </div>
      
      <br><br>
      
       <div class="col-md-9">
       
       
        </div>
      
      
      
      
      </div>
    
  
     
                </div>
    <!-- If its a no -->
               <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-custom-105867-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
    
      
       <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <label type="button"></label>
            Please have a discussion with the employee.
        </div>
      
      
      
      </div>
    
  
     
                </div>
            </td>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>

     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
      
     </fieldset><!-- End Fiedset -->
     
    </div>
    </div>
     <?php }?>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class=" box-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin:0px 10px">submit</button>
     
    </div>
    </form>
        <?php } ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>

<script>
$(".fieldset").hide();
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").hide();
    $(".custom-105965").change(function () {
        $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").toggle(this.value == 'Yes');
    });
 
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").hide();
    $(".custom-105965").change(function () {
        $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1058]").toggle(this.value == 'No');
        $('.alert').show()
    });
 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#startdt").datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showButtonPanel: true,
   yearRange: "-90:+0",
   endDate: new Date(),
   autoclose: true
  }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
   var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
   $('#enddt').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
  });
  $("#enddt").datepicker({ 
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showButtonPanel: true,
   yearRange: "-90:+0",
   endDate: new Date()
  });
  $(".date-picker").datepicker();
   $('.timepicker-default').timepicker();
   $('#report_date').datepicker( {
   format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
  });
  
   $(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Select an option",
    allowClear: true
   });
    $("#asset_type").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == '-1') {
      $("#new_type").show();
     }
     else
     {
      $("#new_type").hide();
     }
    });

    $("#manufacturer").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == '-1') {
      $("#new_manufacturer").show();
     }
     else
     {
      $("#new_manufacturer").hide();
     }
    });

    $("#supplier").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == '-1') {
      $("#new_supplier").show();
     }
     else
     {
      $("#new_supplier").hide();
     }
    });
  });
  

  
</script>
```

Mysql Table is :[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Below Snippet

```
function update_get_resignation_to_act($post_array,$action)
{       
     $this->load->database(); 
     $this->db->where('userids', $post_array['id']); 
     $dbdata = array(
          "discussion" => $post_array['custom-105965'],
          "manager_comments" => $post_array['manager_comments'],
          "last_status" => $post_array['accept'],
          "agreed_date" => $post_array['agreed_last_date']
     ); 
     $this->db->update('pr_resignation_requests', $dbdata);
     /**
     * if required add this code here to check
     *
     * echo $this->db->last_query();
     */
     return;    
}
```

Comment: echo query and run in phpmyadmin.

Comment: can u echo query? and paste on comment

Comment: Employee Initiated67YespopoAccept01-01-1970UPDATE pr_resignation_requests SET `discussion` = 'Yes', `manager_comments` = 'popo', `last_status` = 'Accept', `agreed_date` = '01-01-1970' WHERE `userids` IS NULL

Comment: correct...try to add static user id and try. where userids=1 and echo $post_array['id'] to check

Comment: Problem with where clause. echo  $post_array['id'] and check what value you are getting.once you pass correct value, code will work

Comment: In controller modify $post_array[$id] to $post_array['id']

Comment: solved ! i was passing wrong value from the view now corrected my view , controller and model accordingly . But thanks for your wonderful advice !